# How do I pass post variable through jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http, codeigniter

I have this jQuery call in a click event:

```
var url = "http://www.....";
$('#platforms-lasers-video').load(url + ' #platforms-lasers', {video: 'platforms-lasers'});
```

I am using CodeIgniter and pass $data['video'] = $this->input->post('video') to the view, making sure to pass $data to the view.

I echo like this:

```
<div id="<?php echo $video; ?>">

    <div id="video">
        <video width="650" height="360" controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/features/<?php echo $video; ?>.jpg">
          <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>videos/<?php echo $video; ?>.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
          <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>videos/<?php echo $video; ?>.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
          <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>videos/<?php echo $video; ?>.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
          <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="650" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" />
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/<?php echo $video; ?>.jpg", {"url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>videos/<?php echo $video; ?>.mp4","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/<?php echo $video; ?>.jpg" width="650" height="360" alt="" title="<?php echo $v->no_playback; ?>" />
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="<?php //echo $v->get_flash; ?>" />
            </a>
          </object>
        </video>
       </div>


   </div>
```

But the post variable isn't being passed to the view.  How do I do that?

Comment: `But the post variable isn't being passed to the view`. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Have you tried with: `$('#platforms-lasers-video').load(url, {video: 'platforms-lasers'})` ?? I think the `#` is useless.

Comment: Try to put `'video'` instead of just `video` and try using `$data['video'] = $this->input->get('video');`.Maybe there is a problem with your jquery load method.

Comment: The #platforms-lasers loads a specific div from a page, but nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load()` uses the GET method.

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to **$.get(url, data, success)** except that it is a
>   method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback
>   function.

from [jQuery .load() manual](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

You will need to use `$data['video'] = $this->input->get('video')`

Answer (score 3):

`.load()` uses the `get` method.

To do a `post` you can do:

```
var url = "http://www.....";
$.post(url, {video: 'platforms-lasers'}, function(data){
     $('#platforms-lasers-video').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this seems to be answered for future reference you can also use:

```
$data['video'] = $this->input->get_post('video')
```

This function will search through both the post and get streams for data, looking first in post, and then in get.